# Vaadin GWT compilation fails: nocache.js file not found

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, classpath, widget, vaadin

Whenever i compile my widgetset using the eclipse compilation tool (plugin) and maven install. The tomcat server cannot find this file even though it's placed right under my VAADIN/themes/widgetsets folder?

The error i get isnt very helpful:

```
 Feb 20, 2012 7:20:47 PM com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet serveStaticResourcesInVAADIN
INFO: Requested resource [VAADIN/widgetsets/org.bixin.dugsi.web.DugsiManagerWidgetset.gwt.xml/org.bixin.dugsi.web.DugsiManagerWidgetset.gwt.xml.nocache.js] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.
```

EDIT:

if anyone else noticed this, the file nocache.js is located in **VAADIN/widgetsets/org.bixin.dugsi.web.DugsiManagerWidgetset** but the server is looking in

```
VAADIN/widgetsets/org.bixin.dugsi.web.DugsiManagerWidgetset.gwt.xml/
```

it added `.gwt.xml` to file directory for some reason? how can i fix this

How can i refresh tomcat within eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that the `.gwt.xml` postfix is not in your web.xml. It should be:

```
<init-param>
    <description>Application widgetset</description>
    <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
    <param-value>org.bixin.dugsi.web.DugsiManagerWidgetset</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see detailed Vaadin compilation command on the first few lines of console output by enabling "verbose compilation output" on  Properties -> Vaadin section. Your file may be located in wrong place other than specified in verbose compilation command.

Also, your related file may be located in a directory which has space characters. This may be an error for the compiler.

Error may be caused of another unrelated item too. Probably you can find the real cause by examining verbose compilation output.